# WPF object memory uses in running application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am developing an wpf application. which uses most amount of memory from my ram. i want to know about the memory used by every object running in my application. is there any way to to view all of the object like task managers process view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a .Net memory profiler.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Red Gate ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

Comment: +1 for ANTS.  It has a pretty good user interface and you might actually find your bug without really digging into the program.  However, if you need support debugging your problem, expect to just get directed to their online videos.